# Cloudfoundry VCAP_SERVICES variables are not supplied to container for django

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

I have a dockerized Django application that I want to deploy on SAP Cloud Platform via cloudfoundry cli utility. I have added couple of User Provided Services with their own set of credentials. For example, I added AWS S3 as a User Provided Service and provided credentials for the same.

Now those credentials are available as environment variable as

> ```
> VCAP_SERVICES={"user-provided":[{
>   "label": "user-provided",
>   "name": "s3",
>   "tags": [
>   ],
>   "instance_name": "s3",
>   "binding_name": null,
>   "credentials": {
>     "aws_access_key": "****",
>     "aws_secret_key": "****",
>     "bucket": "****",
>     "region": "****",
>     "endpoint": "*****"
>   },
>   "syslog_drain_url": "",
>   "volume_mounts": [
>   ]
> }]}
> ```

I have .env file where in I have variables defined, eg. AWS_ACCESS_KEY. Usually I pass string value to the variable which is then consumed by my app. But, given that I have configured it via User Provided Service mechanism and credentials are already there, I was wondering how do I get to access those credentials.

Comment: Have you looked at https://pypi.org/project/cfenv/? or just loading and parsing the JSON in your app? Or are you trying to update this info in the `.env` file? You can add a `.profile` script which runs prior to your app starting. It'll have access to VCAP_SERVICES, so the script could take the bound services and populate `.env` accordingly.

Comment: I am trying to update the .env file. Are there any docs on .profile script?

Comment: This explains it a bit more. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile Typically this would be a shell script, so you could use `jq` or `sed` to extract some info and put it into your `.env` file. You're using `python`, so that will be available as well, so technically you could write this as a python script too. Its up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. You have helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to extract service information in Python applications.

1. You can do it programmatically using the [cfenv library](https://pypi.org/project/cfenv/). You would simply integrate this library into the start-up of your application. This generally offers the most flexibility, but can sometimes be difficult to integrate with frameworks, depending on how frameworks expect the configuration to be feed in.
2. You can generate environment variables or configuration files, from your example the `.env` file, on the fly. This can be done using a [`.profile` script](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile). A `.profile` script, if placed into the root of your application will execute prior to your application but inside the runtime container. This allows you to adjust the configuration of your application at just the last moment.

   A `.profile` script is just a shell script and in it, you can use tools like `jq` or `sed` to extract information from the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable and put that information elsewhere (possibly other environment variables or into a `.env` file).

   Because you are pushing a Python application, the `.profile` could also execute a Python script. The Python buildpack will run and guarantee that a Python runtime is available on the PATH for use by your `.profile` script. Thus you can do something like this, to execute a Python script.

   **.profile script**:

   ```
   python $HOME/.profile.py
   ```

   **.profile.py script (made up this name, you can call it anything)**:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   print("Hello from python .profile script")
   ```

   You can even import Python libraries in your script that are included in your `requirements.txt` file from this script.

Comment: I made use of cfenv library Daniel. You were really helpful. On a side note, have you ever had a chance to use CloudFoundry as a part of SAP Cloud Platform?

Comment: I haven't. I work for another company with CloudFoundry related products, so my focus has been mostly on those. There's often overlap though, so I try to help where I can.

Comment: Okay. Thanks once again.